# How to Convert Data Frame to Odd Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a very long data frame that I need to group into a dictionary for input into a program.

The data frame looks like this:

`pd.DataFrame([['ind1', 'north'],['ind2','south'], ['ind3', 'north'],['ind4', 'south'], ['ind5','east']], columns=['individual', 'population'])`

| individual | population |
| --- | --- |
| ind1 | north |
| ind2 | south |
| ind3 | north |
| ind4 | south |
| ind5 | east |

And I need an `imap` dictionary that looks exactly like this:

```
imap = {
   "north": ["ind1", "ind3"],
   "south": ["ind2", "ind4"],
   "east": ["ind5"],
}
```

Is there anyway to convert that dataframe to a dictionary in that format?

I've tried `.to_dict()` `.groupby('population')` `to.list()` and more, but none seem to give that exact formatting. Most seem to have each individual in its own set of brackets. I'm a python noobie, so I'm at a loss for what to eve look for to find help. Any suggestions?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `df.groupby('population')['individual'].apply(list).to_dict()`

Comment: Chris, you're a scholar and very kind person. Thank you! I had something similar, but not quite there. I think I understand the code, except for the ['individual'] part. I see that it doesn't work without it, but can you explain what it does precisely? Thanks again!